# SKProductStorePromotionController update methods not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit, skproduct

I'm trying to use the `SKProductStorePromotionController` introduced in iOS 11 to update the visibility of some in-app purchase promotions I have, and no matter what I try it doesn't work. I've tried fetching the products via `SKProductRequest` and using `SKProductStorePromotionController`'s order fetching method, and I've tried updating both visibility and order. Neither seems to do anything. This has mostly been in debug builds, though I've also done it in TestFlight builds. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I think it might have something to do with this checkbox in iTunes Connect https://db.tt/XEGT49kzYx. I just disabled it and submitted an update, we'll see if it makes a difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the reason this wasn't working for me was because of this checkbox for the IAP in iTunes Connect.

[image]

Once I unchecked that and went through a review the APIs work as expected.

Comment: Looks like this has changed again in iOS 12, my products now show when I’d expect them to hide.

Comment: Is it possible to uncheck this and still let users who do not have your app downloaded see the IAP?